# Setting multiple paths to JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, java, path, bashrc

I am trying to set the JAVA_HOME path in Ubuntu from the .bashrc file
I currently have something like

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_24
```

But I want to also add the servlet libraries in the Tomcat folder to the path.  I tried doing this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_24,/usr/local/tomcat/lib
```

But that just broke the JAVA_HOME path.  How can I add the Tomcat path to the original JAVA_HOME path?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `JAVA_HOME` should only contain the actual Java installation directory. Normally, additional classes should be added to `CLASSPATH`, with directories separated by `:` eg

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/:/somewhere/else/
```

Unfortunately, it seems that Tomcat does its own thing, and that thing has changed with every major version of Tomcat.  [This guide](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath) should help you figure out how to do what you're trying to do with whatever version of tomcat you have.

Comment: Actually, I have this now: JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_24
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/tomcat/lib
export JAVA_HOME and it still can't locate the tomcat libraries during compilation.  Does the order of exporting and setting the variables matter? Is rebooting required?

Comment: @Genadinik if you run `env` what does it show for JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1):

Try separating them with a colon (:).